# HashMap , sorting by values

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Hello can you help me about my sortring problem

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm.put("Berkan Cetin", 100);
hm.put("Mahmut Koca", 78);
hm.put("Rifat Sarili", 89);
hm.put("Cagdas Polat", 61);
hm.put("Gulay Uygun", 56);
```

For example, in there if I want to sort by keys I can use `TreeMap` or else, but I cant find way to sort from biggest to smallest `Integer` according to values.

Thanks

Comment: Dupe of too many to count; just [search for it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+map+sort+by+value&submit=search).

Comment: HashMap has no order.  You have to use a collection which does, or not use a Map. e.g. `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `new TreeSet<String>(map.keySet())` to get a sorted set of the keys..

A map itself is not something that you sort.

Comment: Sorry i could not what did u said.. can you write me all codes to sort it?

Comment: This is not a "can you write me all codes" site. If you're stuck, show your efforts and ask your specific questions. Don't beg for code and make yourself appear lazy.